# cmake doesn't work when install mysql

Tags: mysql, cmake

good afternoon,I'm trying to install mysql-5.5.29 source code on ubuntu.
but cmake just shows:Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
with out any other tips.

```
shell> groupadd mysql
shell> useradd -r -g mysql mysql

mkdir -p /var/lib/mysql

apt-get install bison-dev

shell> tar zxvf mysql-VERSION.tar.gz
shell> cd mysql-VERSION
shell> cmake . -CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="/usr/local/mysql" \
   -MYSQL_UNIX_ADDR=/var/lib/mysql
........
Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I found it works when I just type

```
cmake .
```

but  when I using

```
cmake . -CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="/usr/local/mysql" \
-MYSQL_UNIX_ADDR=/var/lib/mysql
```

errors occurred

```
shell>bison --version
bison (GNU Bison) 2.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're just missing the [`D`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#opt%3a-Dvar%3atypevalue) from your command line args:

```
cmake . -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="/usr/local/mysql" -DMYSQL_UNIX_ADDR=/var/lib/mysql
```